# What is the difference between default and null in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between:

```
t.boolean :test, :default => true
```

and

```
t.boolean :test, :null => true
```

and

```
t.boolean :test, :default => true, :null => true
```

**EDIT**

Does the following make any sense?

```
t.boolean :test, :default => true, :null => false
```

Comment: EDIT answer: It's ambiguous, and I wouldn't want to have to maintain it... ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"null" means "are you allowed to enter a null value in this column"?

Whereas "default" means "if there is a null value in this column ... then use this default value instead"

So, for your examples:

```
t.boolean :test, :default => true
```

"this boolean column will insert a true if you don't bother setting a value for it"

```
t.boolean :test, :null => true
```

"this boolean column will let you set it to true, false or null - and it will stay the way you set it"

```
t.boolean :test, :default => true, :null => true
```

"this boolean column will let you set it to true, false or null... but if you set it to null it will automatically be set to true"

Answer (score 5):

:default - The column’s default value. Use nil for NULL.

:null - Allows or disallows NULL values in the column. This option could have been named :null_allowed.

In the first option, if you don't specify anything, rails will put true
In the second option, it will allow the value to be null.
In the third option, both apply, the values can be true, false and nil

Answer (score 3):

To answer OP's question:

**Does the following make any sense?**

`t.boolean :test, :default => true, :null => false`

Sure, let's take a look at the possible SQL events. (Bear in mind the `default` parameter you set takes effect on `INSERT INTO` statements like the following.)

```
INSERT INTO table_name id, test VALUES 1, NULL; # This should raise an error
INSERT INTO table_name id VALUES 1;             # This will default test column's value to true
```

So, it may make sense - if you want to explicitly disallow `NULL` values (should an attempt to made to set the value to `NULL` directly), and you also want to coerce **missing** or absent values on the `test` column to `true` during `INSERT INTO` statements.